# What does "publish obscurely" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> Some of these have not been published before; others, such as “Living like Weasels” and “The Deer at Providencia,” **were published obscurely**. At any rate, this is not a collection of occasional pieces, such as a writer brings out to supplement his real work; instead this is my real work, such as it is.

What does **to publish obscurely** mean? I know [what obscure means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obscure) but am not sure what it means exactly here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that it was published in a way that makes it difficult to find for most people.  Yes, "Living like Weasels" was published, but maybe it was published in a magazine that has only 5 readers and is not advertised anywhere.  It's published, but almost no one has read it or will read it in the future.  Thus, it is "*obscure*", or *hidden*, or *hard to find*.